# R gsub remove word variation ONLY at end of string

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have the following vector:

```
a <- c("SOCORRO SANTANDER", "SANTANDER DE QUILICHAO", 
       "LOS PATIOS NORTE DE SANTANDER", "LOS PATIOS NTE DE S DER")
```

and need to remove all occurrences of "SANTANDER" or it's abbreviation (and preceding NORTE or its abbreviation, if existing) when they are **only** at the end of string.

So far I've tried (in comment why it fails):

```
gsub("(.*)( N.*DER$)", "\\1", a)       # Fails at SOCORRO
gsub("(.*)( N.*DER$| DER$)", "\\1", a) # Only removes DER at LOS PATIOS
gsub("(.*)([ N.*DER$]|[ DER$])", "\\1", a) # Removes trailing R (??)
gsub("(.*)( N?.*DER$)", "\\1", a)  # Fails removing " NTE DE S" and "NORTE DE"
```

So, in particular, I'd like to know how to adequately remove the unwanted part of the string, **but more in general** I'd like to know the right way to create regexes to test this kind of situations (my first writing was "to use OR (`|`) inside a group", I seriously expected attempts 2 or 3 to work).

Expected result is:

```
a
## [1] "SOCORRO"  "SANTANDER DE QUILICHAO"  "LOS PATIOS"  "LOS PATIOS"
```

Comment: a plus will be explaining why attempt 3 only removed trailing Rs. That puzzles me! Thanks.

Comment: One way to get your output: `gsub("(?:SOCORRO )?(.*?)( N.*DER$)?", "\\1", a) `. I'm sure there are many others.

Comment: @lukeA I appreciate your comment. I over simplified the example, on order to make it short and reproducible. In real data I have many other town names besides SOCORRO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
sub("(.*)(\\s+N.*(DER)$)|\\s+SANTANDER$", "\\1", a)
#[1] "SOCORRO"                "SANTANDER DE QUILICHAO" "LOS PATIOS"            
#[4] "LOS PATIOS"
```

Or

```
sub("\\s+(N(\\S+\\s+){1,}|)\\S*DER$", "", a)
#[1] "SOCORRO"                "SANTANDER DE QUILICHAO" "LOS PATIOS"            
#[4] "LOS PATIOS"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sub('(\\s*\\b(NORTE\\s+DE|NTE\\s+DE))?\\s*\\b(SANTANDER|S\\s+DER)$','',a);
## [1] "SOCORRO"  "SANTANDER DE QUILICHAO"  "LOS PATIOS"  "LOS PATIOS"
```

- We don't need `gsub()`, since we don't need to match multiple times within the same string.
- A bracket expression will match only a single character, hence it's not appropriate for this regex.
- The dollar character is only special when outside of a bracket expression.
- You seem to have tried matching both the abbreviation and full-length words with the same regex piece. I would advise against this; they are conceptually completely different pieces. If a word and its abbreviation happen to share a suffix, then that's circumstantial; you shouldn't build a regex around that fact. Hence I think alternations are most appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanations. I took a load of notes. Regex is hard for us, the uninitiated, and this sort of details help build our understanding. I appreciate your time!